# Can Seasonal ARIMA model be expressed without backshifts?

Tags: arima, seasonality

Every equation of SARIMA I have found involves backshifts. I was wondering if I have an ARIMA model expressed like this:
[image]

is it possible to express it in a similar way, without backshifts? Are there any resources where I can find seasonal ARIMA equation without backshifts?

Comment: Hi: There are ways to write ARIMA ( I'm not famiiar with SARIMA unless you just mean seasonal )  processes as state space models which would kind of avoid the use of the backshift operator but I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I would like to express the SARIMA model similarly to how I have provided the equation for ARIMA. I have found some example for SARMA model here:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36352_01/epm.1112/cb_statistical/frameset.htm?ch05s05s01.html

Based on it how could I apply it to this formula:
https://imgur.com/a/knlbmdA

Comment: Hi: apologies for my lack of understanding but your imgur link is just ARMA(p,q) so I don't know what you mean by your question. you can just add the two more summations if you want to make it an SARMA.

Comment: In the link that I have provided there's an equation for the SARMA model without backshifts. How would such an equation look for SARIMA?

Comment: Hi: I took another look to try and understand given what you said but the link doesn't seem to be showing anything any more ?